# Как отслеживать нажатие клавиш в приложении на PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qlayout, qtoolbutton

Я новичок, и пишу программу для того чтобы она показывала куда нажимает пользователь на клавиатуре и на мыши.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

Я написал некоторый код, но не знаю что делать дальше:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(854, 526)
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.keyboard = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.keyboard.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -30, 681, 351))
        self.keyboard.setText("")
        self.keyboard.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("_im.png"))
        self.keyboard.setObjectName("keyboard")
        self.f1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f1.setObjectName("f1")
        self.f4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f4.setObjectName("f4")
        self.f3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f3.setObjectName("f3")
        self.f2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f2.setObjectName("f2")
        self.esc = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.esc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 21, 31))
        self.esc.setObjectName("esc")
        self.f5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f5.setObjectName("f5")
        self.f6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f6.setObjectName("f6")
        self.f7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f7.setObjectName("f7")
        self.W = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.W.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 90, 21, 31))
        self.W.setObjectName("W")
        self.S = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.S.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 130, 21, 31))
        self.S.setObjectName("S")
        self.A = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.A.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 130, 21, 31))
        self.A.setObjectName("A")
        self.D = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.D.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 130, 21, 31))
        self.D.setObjectName("D")
        self.Ctrl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Ctrl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 220, 21, 31))
        self.Ctrl.setObjectName("Ctrl")
        self.Alt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Alt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 220, 21, 31))
        self.Alt.setObjectName("Alt")
        self.Win = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Win.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 220, 21, 31))
        self.Win.setObjectName("Win")
        self.ShifL = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.ShifL.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 180, 41, 31))
        self.ShifL.setObjectName("ShifL")
        self.Enter = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Enter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 130, 41, 31))
        self.Enter.setObjectName("Enter")
        self.Backspace = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Backspace.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 50, 91, 31))
        self.Backspace.setObjectName("Backspace")
        self.dlt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.dlt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 20, 21, 31))
        self.dlt.setObjectName("dlt")
        self.Tab = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Tab.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 41, 31))
        self.Tab.setObjectName("Tab")
        self.A_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.A_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 21, 31))
        self.A_10.setObjectName("A_10")
        self.ShiftR = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.ShiftR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 180, 41, 31))
        self.ShiftR.setObjectName("ShiftR")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 854, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Клавиши"))
        self.f1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F1"))
        self.f4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F4"))
        self.f3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F3"))
        self.f2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F2"))
        self.esc.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Esc"))
        self.f5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F5"))
        self.f6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F6"))
        self.f7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F7"))
        self.W.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "W"))
        self.S.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "S"))
        self.A.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "A"))
        self.D.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "D"))
        self.Ctrl.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl"))
        self.Alt.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Alt"))
        self.Win.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Win"))
        self.ShifL.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Shift"))
        self.Enter.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter"))
        self.Backspace.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Backspace"))
        self.dlt.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Dlt"))
        self.Tab.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Tab"))
        self.A_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "`"))
        self.ShiftR.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Shift"))


class Example(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.prev_key = []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 9owdl8r, пожалуйста, покажите что вы уже написали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен что правильно понимаю то, что вы хотите сделать. 
Но как вариант, попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


LETTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
NUMBERS = "1234567890"
LUT = {
    "a": QtCore.Qt.Key_A,
    "b": QtCore.Qt.Key_B,
    "c": QtCore.Qt.Key_C,
    "d": QtCore.Qt.Key_D,
    "e": QtCore.Qt.Key_E,
    "f": QtCore.Qt.Key_F,
    "g": QtCore.Qt.Key_G,
    "h": QtCore.Qt.Key_H,
    "i": QtCore.Qt.Key_I,
    "j": QtCore.Qt.Key_J,
    "k": QtCore.Qt.Key_K,
    "l": QtCore.Qt.Key_L,
    "m": QtCore.Qt.Key_M,
    "n": QtCore.Qt.Key_N,
    "o": QtCore.Qt.Key_O,
    "p": QtCore.Qt.Key_P,
    "q": QtCore.Qt.Key_Q,
    "r": QtCore.Qt.Key_R,
    "s": QtCore.Qt.Key_S,
    "t": QtCore.Qt.Key_T,
    "u": QtCore.Qt.Key_U,
    "v": QtCore.Qt.Key_V,
    "w": QtCore.Qt.Key_W,
    "x": QtCore.Qt.Key_X,
    "y": QtCore.Qt.Key_Y,
    "z": QtCore.Qt.Key_Z,
    "Del": QtCore.Qt.Key_Delete,
    "Shift": QtCore.Qt.Key_Shift,
    "Enter": QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter,
    "Space": QtCore.Qt.Key_Space,
    "1": QtCore.Qt.Key_1,
    "2": QtCore.Qt.Key_2,
    "3": QtCore.Qt.Key_3,
    "4": QtCore.Qt.Key_4,
    "5": QtCore.Qt.Key_5,
    "6": QtCore.Qt.Key_6,
    "7": QtCore.Qt.Key_7,
    "8": QtCore.Qt.Key_8,
    "9": QtCore.Qt.Key_9,
    "0": QtCore.Qt.Key_0,
    ".": QtCore.Qt.Key_Period,
    "'": QtCore.Qt.Key_Apostrophe,
}


class KeyBoard(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        letters = LETTERS[: len(LETTERS) // 2], LETTERS[len(LETTERS) // 2 :]
        numbers = NUMBERS + ".'"

        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(*letters)):
            for j, letter in enumerate((a, b)):
                button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
                    text=letter,
                    clicked=self.onClicked,
                    focusPolicy=QtCore.Qt.NoFocus,
                )
                button.setFixedSize(40, 35)
                grid_layout.addWidget(button, j, i)

        for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
            button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
                text=number,
                clicked=self.onClicked,
                focusPolicy=QtCore.Qt.NoFocus,
            )
            button.setFixedSize(40, 35)
            grid_layout.addWidget(button, 2, i)

        for i, text in enumerate(("Del", "Shift")):
            button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
                text=text, clicked=self.onClicked, focusPolicy=QtCore.Qt.NoFocus
            )
            button.setFixedSize(40, 35)
            grid_layout.addWidget(button, i, 13)

        button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
            text="Enter", clicked=self.onClicked, focusPolicy=QtCore.Qt.NoFocus
        )
        button.setFixedSize(85, 35)
        grid_layout.addWidget(button, 2, 12, 1, 2)

        button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
            text="Space", clicked=self.onClicked, focusPolicy=QtCore.Qt.NoFocus
        )
        button.setFixedSize(100, 35)
        grid_layout.addWidget(
            button, 3, 0, 1, 13, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
        )
        self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onClicked(self):
        button = self.sender()
        if button is None:
            return
        widget = QtWidgets.QApplication.focusWidget()

        text = button.text()
        key = LUT[text]
        if text in ("Del", "Shift", "Enter", "Space"):
            if text in ("Shift", "Enter"):
                text = ""
            elif text == "Space":
                text = " "
            elif text == "Del":
                text = chr(0x7F)
        event = QtGui.QKeyEvent(
            QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, key, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier, text
        )
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.postEvent(widget, event)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        font = QtGui.QFont("Arial", 16)

        user_id_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("User ID:", font=font)
        user_id_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(font=font)

        pass_id_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Pass:", font=font)
        pass_id_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(font=font)

        keyboard = KeyBoard()

        flay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(central_widget)
        flay.addRow(user_id_label, user_id_lineedit)
        flay.addRow(pass_id_label, pass_id_lineedit)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(keyboard, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        flay.addRow(lay)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]